# Health check route organisation in microservice(ish) setup behind AWS ALB

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

### How to name health check routes among several services behind ALB?

I'm moving my API and database to AWS. Before moving I split up my monolith REST API into four services:

1. public API (to which apps and websites connects)
2. admin API (for admin web site)
3. messaging API (web socket server for realtime communication with apps)
4. workers (queue based task processors)

I'm now trying to figure out a good organisation of the routes. At first created two subdomains, api.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com.

I directed the api subdomain to my ALB which routed traffic based on the path only, like this:

- "/sockets" -> messaging-api
- "/admin" -> admin-api
- "/" -> public-api

Now I'm trying to implement the health check routes. I'd like to name them "/health". But the health checks needs to be directed to each target group. Since the ALB only routes based on the path I cannot have /health on more than one server.

#### Possible solutions:

### 1. Separate the services via subdomains

I could create a subdomain for each service like:
- api.mydomain.com
- sockets.mydomain.com
- admin.mydomain.com

With this setup I could have a /health in each service without collisions.

### 2. Separate the health check routes via naming

I could name the health check route differently for each service like:

- api.mydomain.com/health-public-api
- api.mydomain.com/health-messaging-api
- api.mydomain.com/health-admin-api

### Suggestions?

Both the above solutions seems viable, but I'd like to know if maybe one of the solutions will bite me later, when for example more services are added, or when I'll add a graphQL API later on.

> **edit:**
>
> I just bumped into one drawback with solution #1. My local
>   dev-enviromnemt is setup with a *docker* image for each service and
>   *nginx* for routing the requests. On top of this I use *ngrok* to be able
>   to reach the dev environment from the Internet.
>
> I think it would be hard to solve the service separation in based on
>   subdomains, but I really don't need the /health routes in the dev
>   enviromnent, so I guess I could just pretend they are not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as documentation and possibly some input to others.

tl;dr:
I went with a third option, separating all services via the first level in the the path. The main difference from my previous structure is that my main api (aka public-api) has moved from the root to a subpath called */app*. I also renamed it to *app-api*.

- api.mydomain.com/**app**/..
- api.mydomain.com/**admin**/..
- api.mydomain.com/**sockets**/..
- api.mydomain.com/**auth**/..
- www.mydomain.com/..

This solution gives me several pros and no cons (I think).

Pros:

- Easy to route request both in ALB and in local dev environment via nginx without the extra work needed for SNI
- subdomains separates api vs web sites very clearly
- /health routes gets unique names by default since they live under separate paths.
- the apps (web and smartphones) can use a common api url (api.mydomain.com/) and still reach all services, i.e. they don't need to store several differently initialized Axios connections. No biggie, but still..

I also opted for making /health a little more future proof and standardized on the following structure in each service.

- api.mydomain.com/servicename/health
- api.mydomain.com/servicename/health/is-up
- api.mydomain.com/servicename/health/is-ready

*up* = responding to requests, *ready* = all dependencies are connected (i.e. databases, etc)

- */health* returns status 200 along with a json object describing the readiness.
- */health/is-up* responds with 200 or nothing (i.e. not reachable at all)
- */health/is-ready* responds with 200 if all dependencies are ready, otherwise 500.

The target groups in AWS will use /is-ready for health checks, but for now it's the same thing as /is-up since I haven't implemented the readiness tests yet.